# Rerun scheduled job with the original run date

Tags: github-actions

I have created a simple workflow in Github Actions that runs daily via a cron trigger. On each run it executes some SQL code that uses `CURRENT_DATE`, which then is the date of the run. However, if the job fails and I have to rerun it on a later date, it will (logically) run with a different date than the first time. In Airflow it can be solved by using `execution_date` and in BigQuery's scheduled tasks there's the `@run_time` variable that is used on retries.

Is there any way I can persist settings used in failed jobs and use again?

Comment: Is the only option to persist the date when the job fails and get this information later? Or would it be an option to retry executing the workflow when it fails as well?

Comment: @GuiFalourd maybe retrying the same date could be an option, but not instantly (since in this case it will likely have to wait some time to run successfully).

Comment: In case of failure, you could add a timer and then retry calling the same workflow again informing the previous date as workflow input, and use it if informed to run the SQL code using it (it triggered through cron job, the input would be empty).

Comment: If it always runs at the same time of the day, couldn't you just always take that time? E.g. if it runs automatically at 6am and you re-run it at 9am, just use 6am. If that doesn't work, another option might be to look at the API and see if you can pull the original time for this run.

Comment: @rethub It's the date I'm after, not the time. Will check the API.